# How do I get Google Calendar feed from user's access token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

Using OAuth I do get access token from Google. The sample that comes with Google and even this one:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.SimpleOAuth2/Program.cs?repo=samples

show how to use Tasks API. However, I want to use Calendar API. I want to get access to user's calendar. Can anybody tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the samples:
[Getting Started with the .NET Client Library](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/dotnet_client_lib)
On the right side of the page linked above there is a screen shot showing the sample projects contained in the [Google Data API solution](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/detail?name=Google_Data_API_Setup_2.1.0.0.msi&can=2&q=). They proofed to be very helpful (I used them to start my own Google Calendar application).

I recommend keeping both your own solution and the sample solution open. This way you can switch between the examples and your own implementation.

I also recommend to use the [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) packages:

- Google.GData.AccessControl
- Google.GData.Calendar
- Google.GData.Client
- Google.GData.Extensions
- [and more ...](http://nuget.org/packages?q=google.gdata)

This way you easily stay up to date.

---

Sample to get the users calendars:

```
public void LoadCalendars()
{
    // Prepare service
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService("Your app name");
    service.setUserCredentials("username", "password");

    CalendarQuery query = new CalendarQuery();
    query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
    CalendarFeed calendarFeed = (CalendarFeed)service.Query(query);

    Console.WriteLine("Your calendars:\n");
    foreach(CalendarEntry entry in calendarFeed.Entries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this one. But problem is I don't want to take password and username from user. I want them to authenticate on Google and then google gives me token and I want to use token and make request. Is there any way where I can use token and get calendar feeds?